# Apply texture on a spherical object without visible seams

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to apply a roughness texture (fingerprints) on my mesh but as my object has a particular form, I cannot think of a way to place seams. As you can see on pictures, the seams I placed for now are too visible (I would like the object to rotate on my finale animation so every side are visible).

If I place my seams elsewhere, then my texture is stretched.

I've searched some solutions and I heard of painting texture in order to avoid visible seams but I would like to know if there are other ways.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that might work depends on what your texture looks like.  You could try going into the UV editing workspace with your object selected in edit mode and all vertices selected.

In the UV editor, use the image selector to select your image texture.  It should show your UV islands imposed on the fingerprint texture.

You can move the islands around in the UV image editor until you've effectively hidden the seams.